# patool not found, although it is already installed

Tags: python

I have the following code which works on one pc with windows 10 but not on another.
I have installed pyunpack, patool and winrar and rar is in the path

```
import os
from pyunpack import Archive

basis_folder =  r'H:\temp'

def unrar_all(basis_folder):
    ext = (".rar")
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(basis_folder):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.lower().endswith(ext):
                print(filename)
                try:
                    arch = Archive(os.path.join(path,filename))
                    arch.extractall(directory=path)
                except Exception as e:
                    print("ERROR: BAD ARCHIVE "+os.path.join(path,filename))
                    print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unrar_all(basis_folder)
```

the error I get

```
python unrar2.py
test.rar
ERROR: BAD ARCHIVE H:\temp\test.rar
patool not found! Please install patool!

pip install patool 
Requirement already satisfied: patool in c:\users\user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (1.12)
```

Comment: Check `python --version` once.

Comment: python --version
Python 3.9.9

Comment: In my case, if the path is invalid or empty, it also return similar message: `ValueError: patool not found! Please install patool! `.

Comment: the problem was with powershell, in command prompt works ok

Answer (score 0):

Big chances that you are running your code with `python 2` and patool is installed only in `python 3` via `pip`.

Runing your code like this may works:

```
python3 unrar2.py
```

Comment: it's on windows 10 and I have only installed python3, if you look at the packages folder it says python 3.9
python
Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why it is not working, but I created a new virtual environment, installed again patool and pyunpack and it's working.
I think there may be a conflict with some other package.